# Java Spring bean that create more instances of another bean

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I have this situation:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/exec", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void execute(){
        int i = 0;
        for (i; i < 10; i++;){
            b.execute(i);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/exec/{i}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void executeSingle(@PathVariable int i) {
        b.execute(i);
    }
}

@Service
public class B{
    public void execute(int i){
        //...a long time...
    }
}
```

Now I call method execute() of A and it takes long time because it call B.execute() consecutively.

I would like to have a parallel approach.

I would create multiple instances of bean B and call them at the same time, so I can gain about 9/10 of the time I spent with the actual "loop solution".

How can I do that?

Now to get these improvements I call 10 times method executeSingle(int i) of A, via browser with multiple HTTP GET like:

GET ADDRESS/api/exec/1

GET ADDRESS/api/exec/2

GET ADDRESS/api/exec/3

...

But I would like to use a more elegant solution.

Comment: Post the code where you are calling "in parallel" all B instances, how are you doing that, using a ServiceExecutor, using your own threads ?? Each time you invoke the rest service one Http-Thread is use to handle the request and each one will require the same time if you use a sleep. So this is natural multithreading of the container. If you want other type of multithreading you need to submit the task of "b.execute" somewhere, in a Executor service or in other place. Another possibility is use AsyncServlets to reduce Http thread pool use

Comment: Please Explain a bit further what do you want to achieve

Comment: @karelss I edit my question: before I write "I would have a parallel..." instead of "I would like to have a parallel...", so I haven't any code about parallel approach. 
With the approach explained at the end of the question I use the container multiheading, making more HTTP GET requests via browser or postman... But I want make only one HTTP GET request and handle by myself the multithreading. I was thinking to create some threads or create more instances of B in the method execute() of A, but I don't know what is the better way.

Comment: ok, as i post on the comment you should use a ExecutorService @Michael Gantman post an example of how to use it, With an executor service you submit task and the executor handle the concurrent execution of the task, you can recive a Future<> to check the status of the process or interact with it, to retrieve the result just call Future<> yourFuture = .............;; yourfuture.get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you need to use [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and in particular [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) Read about them to see how to use it. Then I would do the following changes to your code: change your B class to implement Runnable.

```
    public class B implements Runnable {
      private int myParam;

      public void setMyParam(int i) {
        myParam = i;
      }

    public void run() {
      execute(myParam)
    }

    private void execute(int i) {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Now don't make it a bean and don't inject it into your A class. But make a BclassFactory class that creates and returns a B class (or just create a new B class every time you need it. Now inject into your A class an instance of ThreadPoolExecutor and in your execute method do something like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/exec", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void execute(){
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 10; i++;){
        B b = factory.getB();
        b.setMyParameter(i);
        executor.submit(b);
    }
}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for help, but I can't make the B class a no-Spring-bean class, because it interacts with others Spring beans! 
What do you think abount @Async annotation?

Comment: The fact that your B class interacts with other Spring beans does not prevent you from making  B class a no-Spring-bean class. You now have the factory for this class and every time you need it just get an instance from your factory.

Comment: Yes!!!  I didn't know I can inject a managed-spring-class into a not-managed-spring-class. With your solution I achieved my goal! Thanks!

Comment: Great, I am happy I was able to help you. I saw that you marked my answer as the one that solves the problem. Could you please also up-vote the answer, so the others may find it easier?